# Golang how to derive address from bip32's xpubkey?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, go-lang

i'm trying to derive HD address of bitcoin using Golang. I have extended private/public key. The problem is i'm unable to find any library in Golang that can generate/derive address from the xpubkey/xprivkey. any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on https://github.com/wemeetagain/go-hdwallet

```
// Generate a random 256 bit seed
seed, err := hdwallet.GenSeed(256)

// Create a master private key
masterprv := hdwallet.MasterKey(seed)

// Convert a private key to public key
masterpub := masterprv.Pub()

// Generate new child key based on private or public key
childprv, err := masterprv.Child(0)
childpub, err := masterpub.Child(0)

// Create bitcoin address from public key
address := childpub.Address()

// Convenience string -> string Child and ToAddress functions
walletstring := childpub.String()
childstring, err := hdwallet.StringChild(walletstring,0)
childaddress, err := hdwallet.StringAddress(childstring)
```