# How to use unencrypted mkey to derive all private keys by BIP32 path？

Tags: wallet, private-key, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

The wallet is damaged, I only have the unencrypted master private key, How to recover the wallet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang how to derive address from bip32's xpubkey?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/76951/golang-how-to-derive-address-from-bip32s-xpubkey)

Answer (score 0):

There are tools like:

- the BIP39 tool: https://iancoleman.io/bip39/
- the BIP32jp [https://bip32jp.github.io/english/](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/)

They take a so-called extended key (e.g. "xprv9tuogRdb5YTgcL3P8Waj7REqDuQx4sXcodQaWTtEVFEp6yRKh1CjrWfXChnhgHeLDuXxo2auDZegMiVMGGxwxcrb2PmiGyCngLxvLeGsZRq") as input and output corresponding private keys that can be copied to Bitcoin Core using RPC [importprivkey](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/24.0.0/rpc/wallet/importwallet/) in order to replicate a wallet.